# Year getting converted 1970 when using date in currentTimeMillis()

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I am working on an app where I am saving date in currentTimeMillis() in sqlite database and when I read it I try to convert it to readable format. But date is always being converted to Jan 01, 1970.
Following is my code of Saving it to sqlite database:

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I then try to convert it to readable format in following way:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(attendance.getPicDate());
Date resultdate = new Date(attendance.getPicDate());
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

I am getting the following output:

> Jan 17,1970 19:36

**Edit1:** attendance.getPicDate() value = 1432678159

**Edit2:** when I try to save value it is 1500378235812 but when I read it, it becomes above, My column in table is Integer.

Comment: your calendar object is irrelevant here so you can remove it. What is the value of `attendance.getPicDate()`?

Comment: Have you checked what value attendance.getPicDate() has?

Comment: I have added it as comment

Comment: Those are in seconds, not milliseconds. You're calling `setTimeInMillis`.

Comment: Just multiply this value by 1000

Comment: please check my latest edit

Comment: SQLite time should be seconds, not milliseconds

Comment: Also, sqlite already supports `strftime()`, so why do you need SimpleDateFormat? https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: so you mean while saving I should divide it by 1000? or do we have any other method to convert it to seconds and not miliseconds?

Comment: The problem seems to be with your database, rather than the date formatting. Could you update your question to include the DB access code?

Comment: yes, I found my mistake I was using cursor.getInt(2) to fetch it but now I have corrected it to cursor.getLong(2) and it is working great now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake I was using **cursor.getInt(2)** to fetch date from database but now I have corrected it to **cursor.getLong(2)** and it is working great now.

Answer (score 0):

1432678159 does convert to Jan 17,1970 19:36.

Try checking attendance.setPicDate().

Comment: 1500378235812 converts to Tue Jul 18 2017 11:43:55.

Somewhere along your code you are losing the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you should save date and time in string format in database.

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
String currentTime=sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

save that "currentTime" in your database.